# Proof that Web Gardens do not fly well with InProc Sessions

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I am tinkering with Web Gardens in ASP.NET with IIS 6.0.  Multiple sources ([Source1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/david.wang/archive/2005/09/19/why-do-i-lose-asp-session-state-on-iis6.aspx) [Source2](http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2009/02/on-web-gardens-aspnet-and-iis-60/)) explain how InProc Session does not fly well with Web Gardens.  I built a program to prove it, but the results are difficult to explain.  Please help me explain the results of my testing.
**TEST**
I set the Maximum # of worker processes to 1000 in IIS.
I create a web app that stores a string in Session and retrieves the value with a button click.  Run web app in IE, FF, and Blackberry browsers.  
**RESULT**
***IE***:  Usually pulls session properly.  Session failed after letting the website sit idle for ~3 minutes.
***FF***:  Session <strike>never</strike> rarely failed.  After sitting ~15 minutes Session failed.
***BB***:  Regularly fails.  Ratio is inline with what Source2 says.  The greater the # of worker processes in the Garden, the more likely it is Session fails.

**My Interpretation**
FF/IE/Desktop browsers have more memory which may allows for better caching.

**Notes**
Setting IE to check for newer versions of a page on every visit has no effect.  Noticed that postbacks from the Blackberry are pretty much guaranteed to create a new instance of w3wp.exe, whereas Mem usage increased for the same w3wp.exe process with postbacks from IE/FF.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the browser to have ANY effect on the session state. Are you SURE the browsers behaved differently? What evidence were you looking for that session failed?

Comment: The evidence is that the string is not in session therefore it leads to an object reference not set to an instance of an object when I attempt to populate the TextBox with the Session data.

Comment: What is the cache policy sent with the page to the browser? If you repeatedly hit a page with cache policy it won't go to the server every time. That might make it look like session is alive when in fact it is not.

Comment: @n8wrl As stated in my OP, I set the cache policy in IE to check for newer versions of a page on every visit.  It makes no difference.

Comment: I'm not sure why you felt like doing this.  There is lots of information telling you that inproc doesn't work for multi-proc apps. It's very clear, use SQL server sessions, ASP.net State service (which works fine for a single server) or a third party distributed caching solution.  

Sessions ID's are assigned by the thread when in proc so it's possible to have a matching sessionid for multiple threads but really those represent different sessions.  Short response, DON'T use In-Proc for session if you need more than one thread.

Comment: @Middletone I'm doing this because while I believe it, my job does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that browsers have more memory shouldn't have anything to do with InProc Sessions and WebGardens as those are *server side* components.

You see more issues as you increase the number of worker processes because the more number of worker processes the less likely is that your request will be handled by the same worker process when it comes back. In other words if you only have one worker process you have a 1 in 1 chance that it will go back to the same worker process on a second request; if you have two worker processes you have 1 in 2 chances, if you have three worker process you have 1 in 3 chances, and so on.

I wonder why are you trying to use InProc Sessions, though. There is almost no good reason to as they can vanish very easily. See this article http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/1986.aspx

Comment: Point taken on the server side components. It still doesn't explain the huge variance in results based on browser. The articles I linked in my post already explain the ratio, so that lesson is unecessary. Since MS uses InProc as the default in ASP.NET I trust it is fairly reliable, but that's beside the point.   I'm looking for an explanation of the actual test results.

Comment: MS uses inProc as a default becasue it is the best performing. They repeatedly warn against it for farms and any session state for scalability.

Comment: @n8wrl Agreed. I simply want to prove that fact with consistency or explain the inconsistency in terms of Web Gardens.

Comment: This is a very large company with a lot of moving parts.  Many things could be wrong with these tests.  Gonna just quit on this idea as I've just used online documentation to show that InProc doesn't work well with web gardens.